# IF Values match return true

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to get some code working but when I change a target cell into a range of cells I get an error #VALUE!

this code works

```
=IF(AND(A1=Sheet2!A2,B1=Sheet2!B2),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

but if I add a range I get #VALUE! Error

```
=IF(AND(A1=Sheet2!A2:A10,B1=Sheet2!B2:B10),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Update : Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

[image: Example]

Any help would be much appreciated 
Many Thanks,
And

Comment: How can a cell have the same content than a range ? What is stored inside that range ? If you want e.g the SUM make use of that function for the range.

Comment: A1 is a cell value but Sheet2!A2:A10 is a range. So they cannot be equal.

Comment: Thanks, so A1=NOW() (todays date) so A2 to A10 will have i.e A2 = 19-8-17, A3 = 20-8-17, etc and B1 will have "ONCALL" so in C1 if Todays date was in Cell A5 and B5 contained "ONCALL" the cell C1 would display ONCALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach from your logic statement.  Instead it looks through your table and match the name with the row and the column with the date selected and the pulls the value at that location.

```
=INDEX($B$7:$G$8,MATCH($B3,$A$7:$A$8,0),MATCH(C$1,$B$6:$G$6,0))
```

[image: POC]

IMPORTANT:  The names in you B3:B4 area have to be unique and spelled identical to your A7:A8 area.  That included trailing or leading spaces that you may accidentally drop in.

Adjust reference ranges to match your need if tables are on different sheets of your workbook.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you testing so far seems to work exactly as required

Answer (score 0):

[image]

THIS IS AN ARRAY FORMULA - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> While still in the formula bar

`=INDEX(B2:B10,SMALL(IF(A2:A10=A1,IF(B2:B10="ONCALL",ROW(A2:A10)-1)),1))`

`=INDEX(B2:B10,` - Look through B2:B10 and return the row number calulcaulated by:

```
SMALL(IF(A2:A10=A1,
      IF(B2:B10="ONCALL",
                         ROW(A2:A10)-1)),1))
```

This is building an array of row numbers minus 1 where both IF statements are true (Date matches and "ONCALL" present), SMALL then returns the nth value in ascending order - I have asked for the 1st match (or the smallest row number) which INDEX then uses to return the result.

Comment: Thanks, that didn't seem to work for what I wanted I have added hopefully a clearer example of what I am trying to achieve above, Many Thanks

Comment: @Andy Apologies. I tend to be so busy these days that I only get 5 minute windows to check SO.. Glad someone came along with the answer. I only had the initial information to work with else I would have suggested the exact formula provided in FormulaEd's answer

Comment: Thanks @Glitch_Doctor my first post could have done with a little bit more detail looking back now